# Meteor error on update

Tags: meteor

I'm getting this error when I upgrade my meteor app to the latest version (1.2)

```
Exception in callback of async function: Error: url must be absolute and start with http:// or https://
```

My meteor packages

blaze-html-templates      1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with 
Meteor Blaze

check                     1.1.0  Check whether a value matches a pattern

d3                        1.0.0  Library for manipulating documents based on data

ejson                     1.0.7  Extended and Extensible JSON library

fortawesome:fontawesome   4.4.0_1  Font Awesome (official): 500+ scalable vector 
icons, customizable via CSS, Retina friendly

fourseven:scss            3.4.1  Style with attitude. Sass and SCSS support for 
Meteor.js (with autoprefixer and sourcemaps).

http                      1.1.1  Make HTTP calls to remote servers

insecure                  1.0.4  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes 
from the client
jquery                    1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors

logging                   1.0.8  Logging facility.

meteor-base               1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs

mobile-experience         1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience

mongo                     1.1.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP

pauloborges:mapbox        2.1.5  Mapbox.js for Meteor apps

random                    1.0.5  Random number generator and utilities

react                     0.14.1_1  Everything you need to use React with Meteor.

reactive-var              1.0.6  Reactive variable

reactrouter:react-router  0.1.12  react-router (official): A complete routing 
solution for React.js

reload                    1.1.4  Reload the page while preserving application 
state.

session                   1.1.1  Session variable

spacebars                 1.0.7  Handlebars-like template language for Meteor

standard-minifiers        1.0.2  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by 
default.
tracker                   1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks

any solution?